# How to suppress producing ERRORS to stdout while load testing with Locust.io

Tags: python, locust

While load testing with locust my site, like

```
locust -f mysite_loadtest.py --host=https://beta.mysite.com
```

I use following code(excerpt):

```
class Details(TaskSet):
    """IP details queries group"""

    def on_start(self):
        self.client.verify = False  # Don't to check if certificate is valid 

    @task
    def details_ip(self):
        response = self.client.get("/main")

class TaskList(TaskSet):

    tasks = [Details]


class APIUser(HttpLocust):

    task_set = TaskList
    min_wait = 0
    max_wait = 3000
```

I get a huge amount of ERROR's to stout like:

```
[2017-02-08 05:26:34,988] beta.mysite.com/ERROR/stderr: /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:315: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#snimissingwarning.
  SNIMissingWarning
[2017-02-08 05:26:34,988] beta.mysite.com/ERROR/stderr: /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:120: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
[2017-02-08 05:26:35,008] beta.mysite.com/ERROR/stderr: /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:791: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html
  InsecureRequestWarning)
```

Is it possible to suppress those ERROR's from writing to stdout in any way?

Answer (score 3):

this would ignore warnings  :

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
```

if the solution above didn't work try :

```
import os
import sys
f = open(os.devnull, 'w')
sys.stdout = f
```

this will redirect your error output to null ( it won't be shown).

Comment: I've placed those lines right under imported modules. But still get errors to output.

Comment: i've updated my comment , check the second one , if it still didn't work , please specify the imports that you have in your python script.